# git - get only changed files for specific branch

Tags: git

For our business, we really want to know, which files was changed (add, delete, modify) in specific branch. Let's say, that I have master branch and a lot of something like feature branches, which I always merge to master branch. Now, I want to know, which files are changed for specific branch in the past. Of cource, that I can make diff between first and last commit, but I don't want to study log (it's really pain) and search first commit to make diff, because I'm doing this activity quite often. I want some script, where I put name of the branch and the result will bew list of all changed files, from all commits on the specific branch. I have only one idea, how to make this script - grep commit messages, where have to be name of the branch.. Is there any other way?

```
  A1---A2---A3          BRANCH A
 /            \
M1---M2---M3---M4       BRANCH MASTER
      \            
       B1---B2---B3     BRANCH B
```

Comment: are you using github, or do you have to have a git-only solution?

Comment: I have git-only solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For unmerged branches you can use `diff --stat` and the triple dot

```
git diff --stat ...other_branch
```

to only show changes in `other_branch` and get an output like

```
setup.py        |   1 +
proj/foo.py     |  37 +++++-
proj/bar.py     |  51 +++++---
proj/bin.py     |  71 +++++++++--
proj/baz.py     | 337 +++++++++++++++++++++++++--------------------------
5 files changed, 363 insertions(+), 238 deletions(-)
```

The triple dot will only show changes that are in `other_branch` that are not in in the current branch. Changes that are in the current branch but not in `other_branch` will not be shown.

For an already merged branch you can use

```
git diff --stat $(git merge-base HEAD other_branch)^..other_branch
```

Comment: Thanks, but this will be fucntion only for branches, which are not merged to master. A make simple example of our log.

Comment: Can you amend your question, specifying why and what exactly you want to see for branches that have been merged?

Comment: Thats it! Thanks!